# Unit testing a flask application which requests external resources from other application over REST

Tags: flask

I am very new to writing unit test cases for python and need some help.

I have a Flask based application which internally calls another url over REST

Sample code

```
@sample.route('/testing', methods=["GET"])
def testing():
    resp = requests.get("some url")
    data = resp.json()
    resp1 = requests.post("another url", data)
    return resp1.status_code()
```

Now since for unit testing, my other module is not available yet and i need to write unit test cases for this module.
so i would need to mock these rest requests and return custom data and status code for each request.

Can anyone please help on how to proceed for this.
I tried various links online but not working as per my expectation.

Comment: I always write factories ([Factory pattern](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Factory.html)) when I have problems like these.
You create a request factory with the required needs to perform a get / post request; and with some configuration file, you determine whether you are doing the actual calls or calling mocked data.

Comment: But isn't this integration testing, rather than unit testing?

Answer (score 0):

You can [mock, that is, create a custom mock-up for external APIs](https://realpython.com/testing-third-party-apis-with-mocks/) in a number of ways. In general, it will involve a *fake* API that will return pre-set values when a call is made.
Also, please consider that tight coupling between the two APIs, that might cause problems in the future. Try to reformulate your arquitecture so that it use [looser coupling](https://blog.dreamfactory.com/the-importance-of-loose-coupling-in-rest-api-design/)